# How to print a textbox long text in C# print document (print multiple lines)

Tags: c#, printing

A textbox text text will show something like this e.g (Four hundred and seventy nine thousand three hundred and twenty two cents two five only). I am using following line to print the text.

```
g.DrawString(" " + cnv_txt.Text, new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(72, 144));
```

Its printing whole text into one line. But In my printing paper the line length in 10cm and there are three lines. So this text cannot be print a single line. I need to break texts like these into three lines. how can i do this. 
(I am showing only an example text. It can be change because it is a converted text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with this link its a good article and answer is working.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurecharacterranges(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You should be able to use `Graphics.MeasureString` to get the length of a string, and divide it by splitting it up.</strike>

One of the overloads of `DrawString` takes a bounding box. This should wrap your text automatically.

From the [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring(v=vs.110).aspx) you can add a `RectangleF` parameter to specify the bounding box that the text should be constrained to. It will automatically wrap.

So you should do something like:

`g.DrawString(" " + cnv_txt.Text, new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(72, 144), new RectangleF(0f,0f,50f,50f);`

This will keep it in a 50x50 box.

Comment: can you please provide me a sample code or any links that i can learn from it.

Comment: the provided line of code not done the job its not working